# Taxonomy list names with lowercase

Tags: taxonomy, title

I try to make custom taxonomies names to display with lowercase, but for some reason it doesnt work and show all taxonomy titles with big capital. Here is the code that i use:

```
    $genre = strtolower( strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ', '' ) ) );
if ( is_singular( array( 'dvd','vhs' ) )) {
echo '<meta name="description" content="'. get_the_title() .' is '. $genre .'." />';
}
```

Thank you all in advance :)

**UPDATE**

This is my whole code that I put in functions.php

```
    function test_seo() {


    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre' );
    // var_dump($terms);
    $tnames = array();
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
      foreach ($terms as $t) {
        $tnames[] = strtolower($t->name);
      }
      $genre = implode(', ',$tnames);
    }
    // var_dump($terms);


    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_tax() || is_page() ) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="Test description" />';
    }

    elseif ( is_singular( array( 'dvd', 'vhs' ) )) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="'. get_the_title() .' is '. $genre .'." />';
    }

}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'test_seo');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing seems odd. You are creating and retrieving an HTML string only to strip out the HTML.

Try this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre' );
// var_dump($terms);
$tnames = array();
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
  foreach ($terms as $t) {
    $tnames[] = strtolower($t->name);
  }
  $genre = implode(', ',$tnames);
}
// var_dump($terms);
```

You can un-comment the `var_dumps` to get an idea of what is happening. You can change the first parameter of [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to change the separators-- right now it uses a comma.

Comment: I try your code, but it's the same. All taxonomy names begin with a capital letter.

Comment: I ran my code and it does in fact generate an all lowercase string. I do not know what you are doing wrong but my code does in fact work.

Comment: Wordpress latest version. I register taxonomy, no other plugins and stuff.

In functions.php I put:

`$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre' );
// var_dump($terms);
$tnames = array();
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
  foreach ($terms as $t) {
    $tnames[] = strtolower($t->name);
  }
  $genre = implode(', ',$tnames);
}
// var_dump($terms);

if ( is_singular( array( 'dvd','vhs' ) )) {
echo '<meta name="description" content="'. get_the_title() .' is '. $genre .'." />';
}`

It show on front - **Indiana Jones is Action, Adventure**

Comment: You should be getting errors if you put that in `functions.php`. `$post` isn't defined for one. Are you hooking this code to anything or just running it straight from `functions.php`?

Comment: I update my first post with the whole code, that I put in functions.php. @s_ha_dum realy thank you for help :)

Comment: The modified code works for me when I try it. Something else has to be messing this up.

Comment: After some tests I think I found what is the problem. If my taxonomy is in english for example adventure, everything is ok. If taxonomy is in cyrillic - for example приключение or begin with cyrillic word it begin with Capital letter. This is very strange.

Comment: Use [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)